# Visualforce:Alert message for my successful button

Tags: visualforce

Hi everyone need help with my Visualforce page code I need to insert an alert message for my save button.

```
<apex:page lightningStyleSheets="true" controller="MycustomSettingController">
    <apex:slds /> 
       <div class="slds-page-header">
          <div class="slds-media__body">    
              <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" >Org Information</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <div id="divMainContainer" style="display:flex" class="slds-col slds-size--4-of-4" >
          <div  class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around--xx-Large">
            <apex:form id="theForm">
               <apex:message id="showmsg"></apex:message>
                <apex:pageBlock >
                            Client ID: <br/><apex:inputField value="{!orgInfo.Client_ID__c}" required="true"/><br/>
                            Client Secret: <br/><apex:inputField value="{!orgInfo.Client_Secret__c}" required="true"/><br/>
                            Username: <br/><apex:inputField value="{!orgInfo.Username__c}" required="true"/><br/>
                            Password: <br/><apex:inputField value="{!orgInfo.Password__c}" required="true"/><br/> <br/>
                            Sandbox? <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!orgInfo.Sandbox__c}"/><br/><br/>
                           <br/>
                           <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_success"   action="{!save}" value="save" rerender="showmsg"/>
                  </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Javascript in Commandbutton](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105967/call-javascript-in-commandbutton)

Comment: the problem sir is not a custom object ist a custom setting

Comment: You'd need `ApexPages.addMessages(ex)` to be included in the controller and might need some CSS to make it nice the message. Can you please post your controller logic as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<apex:message>` is specifically used for a specific component, such as a warning or error. Instead use `<apex:pageMessages>` which displays all messages that were generated for all components on the current page.

You'd need ApexPages.addMessages(ex) to be included in the controller Save method as suggested by high-five suggested in comments.

You are using [lightningStyleSheets="true](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm)", so your VF page will be automatically rendered in Lightning UI and apex:pageMessages is also supported and no specific CSS is required.

```
<apex:page lightningStyleSheets="true" controller="MycustomSettingController">
    <apex:slds /> 
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-media__body">    
            <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" >Org Information</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <div id="divMainContainer" style="display:flex" class="slds-col slds-size--4-of-4" >
            <div  class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around--xx-Large">
                <apex:form id="theForm">
                    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
                    <apex:pageBlock >
                        <!--
                        ....
                        -->
                        <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_success" action="{!save}" value="save" rerender="showmsg"/>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class MycustomSettingController {
    public pageReference save(){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'CONFIRM: Account Created.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to show the message as Lightning Toast Message you have to create the custom Toast Message using SLDS. Please go through this dev forum link [can we show toast messages on visual force pages using java-script ?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005XCGQA2) for details.

Comment: the code is code but i after i save the data are still there? what should i do?

Comment: Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: the problem now is the after I click the save button the alert message pop up but still  the data that ive input in the text field  are still there i need now the refresh button to refresh the page

Comment: Please check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63251/how-to-clear-fields-in-a-form-after-hitting-submit